# calling servlet from button inside taskbar of grid extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I want to send textfield data to servlet after clicking button. Textfield and button in tbar of grid. I am using an Ajax request to call a servlet, but it is not calling it.

```
tbar: [{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  name: 'text'
}, {
  text: 'Serach',
  scope: this,
  handler: function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      method: 'GET',
      loadMask: true,
      scope: this,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/sampleweb/AccessServlet',
      success: function (response, request) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('success', response.responseText);
      },
      failure: function (response, request) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('failure', response.responseText);
      },
      params: {
        firstname: text.getValue()
      }
    });
  }
}]
```

Comment: Is logging turned on on your server? If so, do you see the request reach the server? What does your browser's Net panel say happened?

Comment: Maybe there is an error with value loading from that field? Instead of calling `text.getValue()` - use `Ext.getCmp('that_field_id').getValue()`?

Comment: Were you able to call the servlet? I too face the same issue. Unable to call servlet through Extjs

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put http://localhost:8080 in the AJAX request. Just put AccessServlet as the URL
or /sampleweb/AccessServlet

As others have suggested, what is in the net panel of your browser.
What do you see on the server console ?
You can enable debugging on the server to see the request come in.